# Vue router url could not open page

Tags: vue.js

I am using Vue("vue": "^2.5.2") to make a SPA,this is my route("vue-router": "^3.0.1"):

```
routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    }]
```

when I request : http://localhost:8080.It could open the page.But when I tweak the route like this:

```
routes: [
        {
          path: '/home',
          name: 'Home',
          component: Home
        }]
```

And I request : http://localhost:8080/home .It could not open the page.Why would this happen ,how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [vue router docs:](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

> The default mode for vue-router is hash mode - it uses the URL hash to simulate a full URL so that the page won't be reloaded when the URL changes.

You should find your page at http://localhost:8080/#/home

You can read more about this [here](https://router.vuejs.org/)